# Comparing Reflected Types Returns False

Tags: c#

Take the below code snippet...  This code takes two objects - an original object and the same object with some properties that might have changed - and cycles through each property returning a list of all changed properties with their old and new values.

```
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in newProperties)
    {
        PropertyInfo origProperty = origProperties.Where(p => p.Name == property.Name).Single();
        object originalValue = origProperty.GetValue(original);
        object newValue = property.GetValue(updated);

        // This line always evaluates to true
        if (Convert.ChangeType(originalValue, origProperty.PropertyType) != Convert.ChangeType(newValue, property.PropertyType))
        {
            dynamic modification = new ExpandoObject();
            modification.Property = property.Name;
            modification.OldValue = originalValue;
            modification.NewValue = newValue;
            modifications.Add(modification);
        }
    }
```

The line above always evaluates to true.  I've also tried simply:

```
    if (originalValue != newValue)
```

but this also always evaluates to true.

For example, in the Locals window, it shows for both properties {Int32 Id} and the value for both as 11. So, the condition should evaluate to False, but it doesn't.

Any insights?

Comment: `object` is a reference type, so is `originalValue` the same object as `newValue`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.  `originalValue` and `newValue` belong to the same _type_ of object. But, one is the original object, the other is an object with new values.

Comment: @Alex wouldn't that just return the underlying Type?  Of course, the types will be the same, but I want to check the values.

Comment: I am assuming, from the way you are testing, that in the `newProperties` a property type could have changed, while the property name stayed the same, and you want to test for either a change in property type or property value. Is that correct?

Comment: No, the property type will remain the same.  I'm comparing two objects from concrete classes.  I just want to compare the values to see if they've changed.

Comment: Ok in that case I was about to answer what @tgiffin just did, he only needs to add null checks, before calling `Equals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Equals method.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in newProperties)
{
    PropertyInfo origProperty = origProperties.Where(p => p.Name == property.Name).Single();
    object originalValue = origProperty.GetValue(original);
    object newValue = property.GetValue(updated);

    // This line always evaluates to true
    if (!originalValue.Equals(newValue))
    {
        dynamic modification = new ExpandoObject();
        modification.Property = property.Name;
        modification.OldValue = originalValue;
        modification.NewValue = newValue;
        modifications.Add(modification);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add null checks and you are ok.

Comment: @tgriffin Okay so this works.  First, thanks! Second, do you mind telling me why?

Comment: The == operator will compare two reference types to see if they are the same object, whereas .Equals allows you to compare the values. I think the Convert calls you were making resulted in reference types.

Comment: This will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `originalValue` is `null`.